# How to organize a java layout?

Tags: java, layout

How can I make a row of buttons and place this "dungeon attack" logo above the button?
Is there any way to specifically allocate something on the screen? Or is there something that just aligns my components? I'm new to this part of the Java interface

FonteEstilizada is just a class that stylizes fonts for me and BotaoEstilizado only stylizes my button

[image]

My code until now:

```
package atol;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import looks.and.feels.BotaoEstilizado;

public class TestesInterface extends JPanel {

    private Image image;

    TestesInterface(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    }

    public static void run(String endereco) {
  
        final Image image = new ImageIcon(endereco).getImage();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Image");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                TestesInterface imagePanel = new TestesInterface(image);
                imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,10,10,10));
                imagePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));   
      
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                // get 2/3 of the height, and 2/3 of the width
                int height = screenSize.height * 2 / 3;
                int width = screenSize.width * 2 / 3;
                
                JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
                startButton.setUI(new BotaoEstilizado());
          
                JLabel logo = new JLabel("Dungeons Attack");
                logo.setForeground(Color.yellow);
                logo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
                
                startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
                imagePanel.setLayout( new GridBagLayout());
                imagePanel.add(startButton);
                imagePanel.add(logo);
               
                
               

                // set the jframe height and width
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                f.setContentPane(imagePanel);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Creates new form TestesInterface
     */
    public TestesInterface() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                      
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }                    

            
}
```

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with Swing layouts, here's a good place to start: [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: You need to use "constraints" when using the `GridBagLayout` to control the row/column the component is added to. In your case you need the `gridy` constraint. The link above provides information on the `GridBagConstrainsts`.

Comment: Thank you! It works! That's EXACTLY what I needed!